# How to convert DateTimeFormatter to Timestamp sql formate

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to insert DateTimeFormatter to Timestamp in my table Tab1 using JDBC,

```
String d="2020-03-19T21:19:32:921Z";
 DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatterUtc = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSSr3");
 DateTime tD = dateTimeFormatterUtc.parseDateTime(d);
 I have set the date into my dao
 dao.setTRD(transactionOpenDateTime);


 String INSERT_AUDIT_SQL1= "insert into Tab1 (TD) value (?);";
 PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(INSERT_AUDIT_SQL1);
 preparedStatement.setDate(1,(Date) dao.getTRD().toDate());
```

I am getting error like below

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2020-04-16T08:12:16.016+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]" is malformed at ".016+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]"
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.manthan.dao.ConnectionDao.main(ConnectionDao.java:60)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example input does not match the value seen in your error message:

- `"2020-03-19T21:19:32:921Z"` is your given input.
- `"2020-04-16T08:12:16.016+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]"` is reported in your error message.

---

You are working too hard.

Both of your example values comply with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. The *java.time* classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating text. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
Instant Instant = Instant.parse( "2020-03-19T21:19:32:921Z" ) ;

ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( "2020-04-16T08:12:16.016+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]" ) ;
```

You seem to be mixing the legacy date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java alongside [*Joda-Time*](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Instead you should be using the *java.time* classes that officially supplanted both the legacy classes and *Joda-Time*.

Instead of passing `java.util.Date` to `PreparedStatement::setDate`, pass *java.time* objects to [`setObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject(int,java.lang.Object)).

[JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) 4.2 requires support for [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) but, oddly enough, not the more commonly used [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) or [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). So convert.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime() ;

myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

---

You said:

> I am trying to insert DateTimeFormatter to Timestamp

`DateTimeFormatter` is for generating text that represents the value in a date-time object. This class has nothing to do with exchanging information with the database.

The `java.sql.Timestamp` class is one of those legacy date-time classes that you should no longer use. Replaced by `OffsetDateTime` (and optionally, `Instant`).

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Thanks for Quick reply.. can please explain me..because i am new to the java...thanks in advance .

Comment: @RKC All of this has been covered many many many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more. I gave you all the pieces you need.